# .Net Remoting work in Console Application but not work in Window Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-services, remoting

I have a .Net Remoting which work in Console Application but not work in Window Service. Its returns me null type. I don't know whats wrong here

```
static void TicketServer()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    //Console.WriteLine("Ticket Server started...");

    TcpChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel(9988);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, true);

    Type commonInterfaceType = Type.GetType("WindowsService.MovieTicket");

    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(commonInterfaceType,
    "MovieTicketBooking", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
}
```

i get the 'commonInterfaceType' null in Windows service while in Console Application works fine. I have also change the namespace when i shif the application from console to Windows Service

i find the problem but need to know that why this happens in Windows Service, For example in image highlighted line works fine in Console Application, but returns null in Windows service.

http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg339/scaled.php?server=339&filename=testimg.png&res=landing

If i am not wrong i think this is a bug of Microsoft... 
Thank you

Comment: What account is the service running under? Does it have access to the network?

Comment: Dont use remoting it does not work well and was abandoned by MS. Use WCF...

Comment: If commonInterfaceType is null, that means the loader is failing to load the type "WindowsService.MovieTicket". You can look at the Fusion Log (fuslogvw.exe) to find out why. What assembly is the type in? If it's not the same assembly as this code is in, you need to specify the assembly qualified type name. Is the type name and namespace spelled correctly?

Comment: automatic,
use LocalSystem Account, still there is need of access of Network, this is a simple application.

Natza Mitzi,
Due to some reasons i need to use remoting here...

Chris Dickson,
I am using a exact name of assembly in it, i think there is no typing mistake.

Comment: @taha ahmed: `Type.GetType("WindowsService.MovieTicket");` - there is no assembly name here, just a namespace-qualified type name.

Comment: @Chris Dickson I realize that Type.GetType("WindowsService.MovieTicket") returns null in Windows Service only, works in Console Application instead of that if i use typeof(MovieTicket) i can't get the null value

What is the reason behind it, Furthermore should you check the image i attach above

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Set tcpChannel variable outside the body ofTicketServer() method.
What is happening is that the channel is getting dispossed after the method returns.
In console application, we pause the method with a ReadLine() method of the Console class which allows the channel to continue listening and not to be disposed until a key is pressed but that's different with Windows service.